# Can't target input[type=file] with multiple forms on page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have several dynamic forms on a page that each have a file input... How do I do I target the correct file input using $(this) in javascript?

Here is my form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="category_manage.php" method="post">
<div class="plus-button-container">
    <input id="upfile" name="photo" type="file" onchange="submitFormAfterImageCheck();"/>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="sml_image" value="sml_image" />
</form>
```

And here is my javascript function

```
function submitFormAfterImageCheck() {
    var formSubmit = $(this).closest("form");
    var file = $(this).closest('input[type=file]').val();
    alert(file);
}
//gives me undefined
```

I also tried this that works, but only for the first form ...

```
function submitFormAfterImageCheck() {
    var formSubmit = $(this).closest("form");
    var file = $('input[type=file]').val();
    alert(file);
}
```

I think I need something like this, but this gives me undefined

```
var file = $(this).find('input[type=file]').val();
```

Comment: You are using jQuery, use jQuery to bind the events, inline events are bad practice.

Comment: just use the form that you resolved as the context for the file selector: `var file = $('input[type=file]', formSubmit).val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an inlined event handler, inside the event handler `this` does not refer to the changed element.

One easy solution is to pass the changed element as an parameter to the event handler like

```
<input id="upfile" name="photo" type="file" onchange="submitFormAfterImageCheck(this);"/>
```

then

```
function submitFormAfterImageCheck(el) {
    var formSubmit = $(el).closest("form");
    var file = $(el).val();
    alert(file);
}
```

Note: Since you are using jQuery it is better to use jQuery based event handlers instead of inlined ones

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it `submitFormAfterImageCheck` is executing with the global object(window) as `this`.
I'd suggest separating code logic from the markup with jQuery event handlers.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="category_manage.php" method="post">
<div class="plus-button-container">
    <input id="upfile" name="photo" type="file" onchange="submitFormAfterImageCheck();"/>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="sml_image" value="sml_image" />
</form>
<script>
function submitFormAfterImageCheck() {
    var formSubmit = $(this).closest("form");
    var file = $(this).val();
    alert(file);
}
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', submitFormAfterImageCheck);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="upfile" name="photo" type="file" onchange="submitFormAfterImageCheck(this);"/>
```

and :

```
function submitFormAfterImageCheck(source) { 
    alert($(source).val());
}
```